# the sound change following ㄹ

Tags: pronunciation

According to Naver dictionary,

볼거리 [볼꺼리]  vs 갈기다  [갈기다]

일당 [일땅] vs 일다 [일:다]  (For this pair, I guess it is because 일 in the second one is long. If that is true, since many Koreans do not differentiate between long and short sounds, is it OK to pronounce 일다 as 일따?)

Anyway I am confused by the sound change after ㄹ, and similarly after some other sounds like ㅁ.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Related: [Why is the initial consonant of the second syllable of 현장 not tensed (된소리)?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/4762/why-is-the-initial-consonant-of-the-second-syllable-of-%ed%98%84%ec%9e%a5-not-tensed-%eb%90%9c%ec%86%8c%eb%a6%ac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I did some my own research and found a phenomenon called "Non predictable tensing" in *The sounds of Korean A pronunciation Guide by Choo M., O'Grady W.*

Examples from the book: 시가 [시까] 치과[치꽈] 잠보[잠뽀]

I guess the examples I provided before come under this category.